# Create a cake divided in 4 buttons in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am not able to create a cake divided in 4 buttons as shown in [attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNKW.png).
I've got all png image, I start with the center circle that I align it to center without problems, but I'm not able to align the 4 buttons so that the project remain aligned.
I hope that you understand what I want to do; my English is poor.
Thank you very much

I'm using Android Studio and I'm programming in Java to create an android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to RelativeLayout, it's more easy to align for stuff like this.

Comment: RelativeLayout does not allow me to attach them next.

Comment: What do you mean? you can set one to topParent true and leftParent true and then align the rest conseguently

Comment: Ok, I resolved my trouble only setting the adjustViewBounds option. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use 4 images like [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and use them

1   2

3   4

and click listeners for all of them

Comment: The clickable area must be at the center of the circle. This method allow me to click all the area.

Answer (score 0):

Use 4 imageView, then SetOnClickListiner to each of them

Comment: I know how to let them clickable, but I'm not able to align them. The ImageView must be attached

Comment: The user Logic answered what I wanted to say in different words - I don't think aligning the 4 image views is complicated. You just put them in relative layouts and set the gravity of each layout accordingly.
From the question you asked Logic, it seems you need 5 clickable zones - the 4 zones you mentioned and the circle in the middle. In which case the solution is more complicated...and involves good control of Canvas.